The probability that all magic balls will eventually disappear: A branching processe
The problem is that we are given a magical ball. Every second (starting from $t = 0$), it either disappears, duplicates, or triplicates with equal probability. All balls are independent from each other. The question is, what is the probability that all balls disappears eventually?
So, the way I solved this was to consider a recurrence $x = \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3}x^2 + \frac{1}{3}x^3$, since each ball is independent and the probability that two balls disappear is just the probability that one ball disappears, squared.
The only problem is that this equation has two non-negative solutions, $x = 1$ and $x = \sqrt{2} - 1$. I believe the correct answer is the latter, but I'm unable to show why.
I've tried to find a non-zero lower bound on the probability that the ball does not disappear. The way I attempted this was to define a family of random variables $X_t$ which is the random variable that represents the number of balls at time $t$.
Then, I tried using Reverse Markov's inequality which states for $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^+$ such that $\mathbb{P}(X_t \leqslant \alpha) = 1$, then $$\mathbb{P}(X_t \geqslant \beta) \geqslant \frac{\mathbb{E}[X_t] - \beta}{\alpha - \beta}$$ and since $\mathbb{E}[X_t] = \left(\frac{5}{3}\right)^t$ and the smallest value of $\alpha$ that satisfies the conditions is $\alpha = 3^t$, I get
$$\mathbb{P}(X_t \geqslant \beta) \geqslant \frac{\left(\frac{5}{3}\right)^t - \beta}{3^t - \beta}$$ which goes to $0$ as $t \to \infty$, which did me no good. I tried working with the variance but I don't know of any lower bounds involving that (Chebyshev is an upper bound).
If anyone can find a lower bound or a different way to solve this problem, that'd be much appreciated!

Here, I provided a proof that directly answers the question (you may also refer to text books on branching processes for a general theory, while I am not sure where exactly your question has been addressed).
Let $C_{i,t}$ with finite mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ denote the number of copies of the $i$th member in $t$th generation appearing in the next generation, which are  independent when fixing $t$. We have
$$X_{t}=\sum_{i=1}^{X_{t-1}}C_{i,t-1}.$$
Then, by the two laws of total expectation and variance for any $t\in \mathbb N$:
$$\mathbb E(X_{t})=\mathbb E(X_{t-1})\mu$$
$$\text{var}(X_{t})=\mathbb E(X_{t-1})\sigma^2+\mu^2\text{var}(X_{t-1})$$
with $\mathbb E(X_{0})=1, \text{var}(X_{0})=0$, which imply
$$\mathbb E(X_{t})=\mu^t$$
$$\text{var}(X_{t})=\frac{\sigma^2(\mu^{2t}-\mu^t)}{\mu(\mu-1)}.$$
Then, by the second moment method, we have
$$\mathcal P(X_{t}>0)\ge \frac{E(X_{t})^2}{E(X_{t})^2+\text{var}(X_{t})}.$$
As $t\to \infty$, the LHS tends to 1 for $\mu>1$, which is the case for the specific problem in the OP as $\mu=\mathbb E(C_{i,t})=\frac 5 2 > 1$, and the LHS tends to $\frac{\mu(\mu-1)}{\sigma^2+\mu(\mu-1)}$ for $\mu<1$.

Your problem is a very standard one of Branching Processes, or Galton Watson processes. You will find clear explanations in the book by Harris,
Branching Processes 1963 Springer, now re-edited in Dover. Your approach is excellent.
